# Change content text within <p> but retaining <a> tag in same position of content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code

```
<p class='par'>some text goes here <a class='link' href='#somelink'>Link</a> Text continues here</p>
```

And I want to change the text within the p and the a tags but retaining the position of the a tag where it is right now.

```
var cache = $('.par').children();
$('.par').children().remove();
$('.par').text('new text');
$('.par').append(cache);
$('.link').text('new link text');
```

But this of course is appending the a tag to the end of the string.
Any suggestions?

Comment: You could retrieve the link rather than the whole child list, then delete the whole child list as you already do, add the stored link then the text

Comment: Can't we just create the HTML string?

Comment: but that would still not retain the original position... I guess!

Comment: Can you give  some sample output?

Comment: what do you mean  Rejith R Krishnan?

Comment: @adrian void means something like "expected output is `<p class='par'>new text <a class='link' href='#somelink'>new link text</a> Text continues here</p>`"

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this using [**`nodeType`**](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_nodetype.asp). Then you can change value using [**`textContent`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) property.

> For a text node, the nodeType property will return 3.

```js
//set new value
elements = $('.par').contents().filter(function() {
  return this.nodeType == 3;
});
elements[0].textContent = 'New text ';
elements[1].textContent = 'New text 1 ';
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class='par'>some text goes here <a class='link' href='#somelink'>Link</a> Text continues here</p>
```

Comment: I think this is the closest thing I need... I'll give this a try first as of course my content is dynamic :)

Comment: what if the text I want to replace with is one whole string and not split?

Comment: @adrian I did not understand

Answer (score 1):

You could also do this

```js
$('p').contents().map(function() {
  if (this.nodeType == 3) this.textContent = 'New Text';
  if (this.nodeType == 1 && this.nodeName == 'A') this.textContent = 'New Link Text';
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class='par'>some text goes here <a class='link' href='#somelink'>Link</a> Text continues here</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try the following script:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        var hrefTag = $('a').attr('href');
        var ClassTag = $('a').attr('class');
        $('p').html('<a class="' + ClassTag + '" href="' + hrefTag + '">Link</a>');
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class='par'>some text goes here <a class='link' href='#somelink'>Link</a> Text continues here</p>
```

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
var p =document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0]
var a =p.getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
p.innerHTML='';
p.appendChild(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this snippet will be useful

```
var cache = $('.par a'); //  will select a inside .par
var _lastText = " this is last part"; 
$('.par').empty(); // Will empty p tag
$('.par').text('new text ');
$('.par').append(cache);
$('.link').text('new link text'); 
$('.par').append(_lastText)
```

[Working JSFIddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/qhopknej/)

Answer (score 0):

You can split the `<a>` tag and change the position where is your text inside 'p' and outside 'a'

```
$(".par").html($(".par").html().replace($(".par").html().split('<a')[0], 'new first part text'));
$(".par").html($(".par").html().replace($(".par").html().split('/a>')[( $(".par").html().split('/a>').length - 1)], 'new continue text'));
```